# My Google map is not clickable after scrolling to another page of my IonTab

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

I program on Ionic React, when I try to test my app on Android my map shifts up and is no longer clickable after scrolling to another page of my IonTab.

What I noticed:

- No problem on browser
- It doesn't do it on the other pages of the app.
- No errors in the console
- On android I have a swipeback feature that I don't have on the browser, can this cause the problem?

My tabs : Tab1, Tab2, Tab3 (my map)
I use : capacitor/google-maps 5.1.0
capacitor/android : 5.0.3

I tried disabling the backspace function by swiping but was unsuccessful.

I've tried reloading the page each time the view is loaded, but that's not a long-lasting solution.

```
const App: React.FC = () => (
<IonApp >
  <IonReactRouter>
    <Menu />
    <IonTabs>
      <IonRouterOutlet id='main'>
        <Route path="/" exact={true}>
          <Redirect to="/Tab1" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/pages/Contact/Contact" component={Contact} strict={true} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/pages/FAQ/FAQ" component={FAQ} strict={true} exact={true} />
        <Route path='/pages/AboutUs/AboutUs' component={AboutUs} strict={true} exact={true} />
        <Route path='/pages/AccountPage/AccountPage' component={AccountPage} strict={true} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/pages/Welcome/welcome" component={WelcomePage} />

        <Route exact path="/tab1" component={Tab1}>
          <Tab1 />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/tab2" component={Tab2}>
          <Tab2 />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/tab3" component={Tab3}>
          <Tab3 />
        </Route>
      </IonRouterOutlet>
      <IonTabBar className='ion-tab-bar' slot="bottom">
        <IonTabButton tab="tab1" href="/tab1">
          <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={home} />
          <IonLabel>Home</IonLabel>
        </IonTabButton>
        <IonTabButton tab="tab2" href="/tab2">
          <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={speedometer} />
          <IonLabel>Compteurs</IonLabel>
        </IonTabButton>
        <IonTabButton tab="tab3" href="/tab3">
          <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={navigateOutline} />
          <IonLabel>Trouver ma borne</IonLabel>
        </IonTabButton>
      </IonTabBar>
    </IonTabs>
  </IonReactRouter>
</IonApp>
);

export default App;
```

My Tab3.css

```
capacitor-google-map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.map-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100%); 
  z-index: 1;
}
.logo-container {
  height: 18%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.logoUp {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.titrePage {
  color: #046465;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 60%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.searchBar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  z-index: 999;
}
ion-content {
  --background: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

My tab3.tsx only the end of my code :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    createMap();
  }, []);
  
  
  return (

    <IonPage>
    <IonToolbar color={'tertiary'} className='toolbarTop'>
      <IonButtons slot="start">
        <IonMenuButton
        />
        <IonTitle> Mes bornes </IonTitle>
      </IonButtons>
    </IonToolbar>
      <IonContent scrollY={false}className='content-container'>
        <div className="logo-container">
          <IonImg className='logoUp' src={LogoUC} /> 
        </div>
        <div className="map-container">
          <IonSearchbar color={'tertiary'} 
            className='searchBar'
            placeholder="Rechercher un point"
            value={searchTerm}
            onIonChange={(e) => {
            setSearchTerm(e.detail.value!);
          }}
          ></IonSearchbar> 
          <capacitor-google-map 
            ref={mapRef} 
            id='map'
          >
          </capacitor-google-map>
        </div>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Tab3;
```

[image]

Comment: I edited my post, but I'm not sure what more to provide from my code.

Comment: scrolling to another page of my IonTab - What?

Comment: I was not very clear, there is an Ionic Tab component that allows you to make a menu with several pages, and when I click on one of them and I scroll up and down the problem occurs.